# How to group mails by sender but sort by date in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I would like see mail in Outlook as I would in a chat client. So at the top you see the person who sent you a mail most recently.

Grouping mail by sender results in almost the correct behaviour, where I can see the different people in that folder and I can expand a person to see *all* their mail in that folder. But now the tricky part: I only want them to **group** by sender, not to **sort**. I want them to **sort** by last recent mail. Like in a chat client such as WhatsApp.

The "conversation" checkbox does not help either because it's not grouped by sender anymore... Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you would like to see, but there is no such function or feature in current Outlook clients. :(

[UserVoice](https://outlook.uservoice.com/) is a way to submit the feedback. More votes, more opportunity to bring Outlook product group's attention. :)